# When does a lease become legally binding

Tags: contract-law

If I leased an apartment in Texas but signed the papers in CA and faxed them to the apartment in Texas, when or where does the lease become legally binding?  If I need to take them to small claims court could I do so in CA since the lease was signed in CA?

Comment: The lease probably has a term defining venue. A CA court, even if it had constitutional authority to exercise jurisdiction would probably decline to do so under the doctrine of forum non conveniens unless the defendant was a CA based business.

Answer (score 1):

When you communicated your acceptance of the terms; that is, when the fax transmission was complete.

The lease will be subject to Texas law: you could start a case in California but the court may decide or the other party may successfully petition to have it moved to Texas.